# Calculation result is different depending on decimal or double

Tags: .net, vb.net, math, double, decimal

Can someone please explain why the calculated value 180 * 2.2 will be different when stored in a decimal vs. a double; and perhaps also explain why .NET is calculating 180 * 2.2 with a decimal point in the first place?

- Standard Calculator: 396
- Expression (Double): 396.00000000000006
- Expression converted to decimal: 396

[image: Visual Studio Watch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubles are not an exact representation: there is a lot of rounding and truncation (but you do get a much greater range).

Reading: [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).